# How to prevent XML reformatting in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Updated an xml file in order to remove an unnecessary field using 
`deletexml(xmltype(xxx)).getClobVal()`
but the XML returns as one long string instead of a properly formatted XML file with indents and spaces. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`getClobVal`, getStringVal are deprecated since oracle 11.2 .instead of these function you have to use `xmlserialize`.

Example:

```
 select xmlserialize(document xmltype('<a><b><c>xxx</c></b></a>') indent size=2) from dual;
```

And you will end with clob object containing pretty-print xml.

Answer (score 0):

*"properly formatted XML file with indents and spaces"*

That might surprise you, but that is properly formatted (well-formed) XML. The XML standard says nothing about whitespace between structural elements, except that it is allowed. It's called "insignificant white-space" for a reason.

If you want to format your XML for human-readability, you must do that yourself. But XML isn't for humans, it's for machines, so there is no reason to have your SQL do such formatting. Use any tool you like that auto-formats XML for human readability if you want to inspect the XML as human.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm just confused as to why this simple sql function would change the entire layout of the xml. Any suggestions on tools I can use to keep the xml human-friendly?

Comment: Well, the database will parse whatever you input and have an internal representation of the data in some way. When it outputs it will use the most efficient way to return the data. Asking for tools is offtopic on Stackoverflow, but most common text editors (notepad2, notepad++ come to mind if you're under Windows), or even any browser can "beautify" XML.

Answer (score 0):

I use this procedure to make a pretty XML:

```
PROCEDURE MakePrettyXml(xmlString IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB) IS

    xmlDocFragment DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDOCUMENTFRAGMENT;
    xslProc DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.PROCESSOR;
    xsl DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.STYLESHEET;
    xmlStringOut CLOB;

BEGIN

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xmlStringOut, TRUE);
    xslProc := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.NEWPROCESSOR; 
    xsl := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.NEWSTYLESHEET(
        '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">'||
            '<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>'||
            '<xsl:template match="@*|node( )">'||
                '<xsl:copy>'||
                    '<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node( )"/>'||
                '</xsl:copy>'||
            '</xsl:template>'||
        '</xsl:stylesheet>', NULL);

    xmlDocFragment := DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.PROCESSXSL(p => xslProc, ss => xsl, cl => xmlString);
    DBMS_XMLDOM.WRITETOCLOB(DBMS_XMLDOM.MAKENODE(xmlDocFragment), xmlStringOut);

    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.FREESTYLESHEET(xsl);
    DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.FREEPROCESSOR(xslProc);

    xmlString := xmlStringOut; 
    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(xmlStringOut);

END MakePrettyXml;
```

But note the output is a `CLOB` rather than a `XMLTYPE`, you may need some additional conversions.